# Calling WCF Services with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf

I have 2 projects from which I need to call WCF services. 
I have a problem calling services from one of them. 
Therefore I made a simple service which is identical in both projects called Test1.
The SVC, ISVC and the Web.Config files are identical.
Any ideas what else can influance and be the reason why one project is working file and the other return a Bad request error.
I am working with Visual studio 2012.
Following is my code:

SVC file:

```
namespace Proj1.Web
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Proj1SVC : IProj1SVC
    {
        public string Test1()
        {
            return "Project 1";
        }
    }
}
```

ISVC file:

```
namespace Proj1.Web
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IProj1SVC
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test1();
    }
}
```

Web.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Proj1dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Proj1Comp\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Proj1dbKK;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <roleManager enabled="true"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <!--        <authentication mode="Windows"/> -->
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <!-- The name, protection, and path attributes must match 
           exactly in each Web.config file. -->
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" protection="All" path="/" domain="kk.Proj1.com" timeout="600"/>
        </authentication>
        <!-- Validation and decryption keys must exactly match and cannot
         be set to "AutoGenerate". The validation and decryption
         algorithms must also be the same. -->
        <machineKey validationKey="SomeValidationKeyInHex" decryptionKey="SomeDecryptionKeyInHex" validation="SAA1"/>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="administrators"/>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    </system.web>

    <!-- Added for server side authentication data to be available in the WCF service -->
    <!-- STX -->
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL="false"/>
            </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <!-- ETX -->

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
        <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging
             logEntireMessage="true"
             logMalformedMessages="false"
             logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
             logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
             maxMessagesToLog="3000"
             maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
      </diagnostics>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: any exceptions or errors?

Comment: I get error 400: Bad request.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify attributes at operation level in the service contract file for each method or operation. To do this, decorate the method with WebInvoke, which marks a service operation as one that responds to HTTP requests other than GET. Accordingly, your operational level code in the contract file will be as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string Test1(string Id);
```

You need to change the default configuration created by Visual Studio in Web.Config file for WCF services, so that it works with the HTTP protocol request send by jQuery client code.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
     <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
        contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
   </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Call ur service using jQuery.ajax()

```
function CallService() {
    $.ajax({
        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url, // Location of the service
        data: Data, //Data sent to server
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
        success: function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
}

function ServiceFailed(result) {
    alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
    Type = null;
    varUrl = null;
    Data = null; 
    ContentType = null;
    DataType = null;
    ProcessData = null;
}
```

Comment: [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] is not required since this is the default. My web.config has been changed to work with HTTP POST requests sent from JQUERY (look at my code). My JQUERY code is identical to what you posted. as I wrote the same code I posted is working in one project but does not work in another project so I assumed there must be something else which influance it.

Comment: please check if both ur config files are identical

Comment: The files are identical